# Correctly implement of an object rotation

Tags: actionscript

How can I correctly implement 360 degree rotation of some object, every time when some condition is meet?

I have two class, one with definition of function and second with `setInterval()` function. The problem is that the 360 degree rotation is performed only once, even if later also occurs this condition.

First class (A):

```
function rotObject()
{
if(rot < 360)
{
 _root.myObject._rotation = _root.myObject._rotation + 10;
}
else
{
clearInterval();
}
rot = rot + 10;
}
var rot = 0;
```

Second class (B):

```
class B extends MovieClip {
if (<something>) {
setInterval(A.rotObject, 10);
}
}
```